# What are "YEC" and "https-e" mentioned in Tor Browser 11.0.1 changelog?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Quotations from the changelog:

> Bug 40059: YEC activist sign empty in `about:tor` on RTL locales

> Bug 40383: Workaround issue in https-e wasm

I assume this has something to do with Tor Browser localization in languages that are read and written from right to left and "...-e" could stand for "experimental" or "enhanced".

Wikipedia has no clue and Tor Browser User Manual is lacking a Search feature.

Comment: Let's hope Tor Browser developers stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 0):

1. 'YEC' stands for the [Year-end campaign](https://blog.torproject.org/privacy-is-a-human-right/), which is Tor Project's year end fundraiser.
2. 'https-e' stands for HTTPS Everywhere extension that comes bundled with Tor Browser (see: https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser-build/-/issues/40383 for more details on the bug).